# Facebook::Graph Could not fetch access token TLS Support not available

Tags: perl, facebook-graph-api

Im' trying to use facebook api with perl module [Facebook::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/~rizen/Facebook-Graph-1.0600/lib/Facebook/Graph.pm)

First step, get che code:

```
my $fb = Facebook::Graph->new(
        app_id          => 'xxxx',
        secret          => 'xxxx',
        postback        => 'http://xxxxx/fb_postback',
    );

      my $uri = $fb
        ->authorize
        ->uri_as_string;
```

Now I have the code param and I try to get the auth token:

```
$fb->request_access_token($RETURNED_PARAM_CODE);
```

The server log this error:

```
 Could not fetch access token: TLS support not available on this system at perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/Facebook/Graph/AccessToken/Response.pm line 26.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `Net::SSLeay` and `AnyEvent::TLS`, or better upgrade `Facebook::Graph` to >= 1.0502.

Comment: thanks for the answer. AnyEvent::TLS is installed,  Net::SSLeay: 'Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible'. My current version of FB::Graph is the latest = 1.0600

Comment: [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and describe the SSLeay installation problem. Provide the whole log of the installation, not just the last line.

Comment: Worked, installing Net::SSLeay, AnyEvent::TLS and libssl-dev, thank you.